# Fetch the records from Kafka topic within specific date range using KafkaItemReader (Spring batch job to read kafka streams)

Tags: spring-batch, kafka-consumer-api

Is there a way i can read the records from Kafka topic in spring batch job which is using KafkaItemReader for specific date range?

Comment: What do you mean by date range? Are you referring to message timestamps (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768429)? How would you do that without Spring Batch?

Comment: Yes, it means when the message was first published onto the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported for now, you need to write a custom reader or use an item processor to filter out messages that are outside the range (filtering data is a typical use case of an item processor: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#filteringRecords)

Comment: My problem statement is basically to read the messages for a particular day in one run of my spring batch and next day i would like to read the messages for next date. I don't want to read them in a go and then filter afterwards. i want to read the messages selectively and send to ItemWriter without filtering.

Comment: That makes sense and I believe it is a typical use case for the `KafkaItemReader`. If you manage to do it without Spring Batch, please share your findings. We can see how to improve the current `KafkaItemReader` to support that.